# Joomla API 12.1 Cli JTable returns false when trying to instantiate the Content Table

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I have found several examples online, but they all seem to use the older API versions of Joomla and do not work with the 12.1 API.  I'm sure it is something simple I'm missing, but I cannot seem to find it.

```
// all my bootstrapping stuff here

require_once( "../configuration.php" );

$kConfig = new JConfig;

$kDb = JDatabase::getInstance( array(
        'driver' => $kConfig->dbtype,
        'host' => $kConfig->host,
        'user' => $kConfig->user,
        'password' => $kConfig->password,
        'database' => $kConfig->db,
        'prefix' => $kConfig->dbprefix
    ) );

JFactory::$config = new JRegistry( $kConfig );

$kPage = new CPage( ROOT_DIR."/index.html" );
echo "injecting: ". $kPage->m_strTitle."\n";
echo "\t". $kPage->m_strKeywords."\n";
echo "\t". $kPage->m_strDesc."\n";

$table = JTable::getInstance( 'Content', 'JTable', array( 'dbo' => $kDb ) );

var_dump( $table );

output:  bool( false )
```

I will continue to research, however rather than continuing to beat my head against the wall, I wanted to ask here to see if anyone has done anything similar.  And before the question gets asked - the purpose of this script is to migrate existing static html into the Joomla! site.  And no this cannot be done manually due to the volume of pages that need to be converted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you properly bootstrapping the Platform?  For 12.1, you need to be using the legacy bootstrap (https://github.com/joomla/joomla-platform/blob/12.1/libraries/import.legacy.php) to get JTableContent loaded due to the file's physical location changing.

Comment: Perfect, that was it - not sure how I missed that.  Thank you for the help I really appreciate it!